# Can't execute PHP on my localhost

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute a PHP script on my localhost but it's showing the script itself instead of executing it. I am using XAMPP on Mac. Any ideas how can I resolve this problem and see an actual execution instead of a script?

Comment: That means Apache isn't using PHP to render the file and instead outputting the source.

Comment: It's one of two things. 1) PHP module is not enabled, or 2) Apache isn't recognizing that the file extension should be interpreted by the PHP module.  Probably the latter.

Comment: Have you made sure that Apache is turned on from the XAMPP control panel?

Answer (score 2):

i don t think that the problem is with the **FileMatch**

if you go to

> `http://localhost`

and the Xamp admin panel shows that means you are ok with the extension.

did you start the script with? :

> `<?php`

you have to put the script between the tags:

```
<?php echo 'HEllo world!' ?>
```

Otherwise it will be interpreted as text and will be handled by the client side like plain html instead of the server.

Comment: yes. the script is correct and admin panel greets me saying that installation was successful. Thank you

Comment: so the admin panel shows but your script doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you forgot to associate .php files with php. Add this to your apache configuration:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

and restart apache. For more information, refer to the [official instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php).

Answer (score 0):

In XAMPP, the php module is already actived and configured.
Can you post the code?
If you go on localhost/ you see some like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1yO6.jpg) ?
Can you run the demos on the left?

Comment: It shows that I successfully installed xampp and it's ready.Thank you

Comment: Can you run the demos?
Post your code.

Comment: It worked. I changed permission on htdocs. Thanks everybody for helping me